# How to Safely Move Dot/Config Files into Subdirectory by Updating their Path References

Tags: linux

Currently I have the following dot files in my home directory that I would like to safely move into a subdirectory:

- .bash_logout
- .bash_profile
- .bashrc
- .gtkrc-2.0
- .lyxauth
- .pki (this is a directory)
- .xprofile
- .Xresources.

For examplle, I know ~/.bashrc's path is referenced by ~/.bash_profile, and so that would need to be updated were I to move ~/.bashrc to ~/.config/.bashrc. I do not know if the ~/.bashrc path is referenced elsewhere.

So in short, I am hoping to find out what files will need to be updated for each file in the above list in order to move them all into my ~/.config directory.

Answer (score 0):

Best to ask on the unix stack exchange site than here.
You should be able to

1. Search for the config file online to see which program it belongs to
2. See where else the program looks for that file
3. Move and rename the file accordingly

This is how I cleared out my home directory at least.

P.S there are a lot of files, .bashrc for instance, that you shouldn't move,
[you might find this article useful](https://bertptrs.nl/2017/03/06/cleaning-up-the-home-dir.html)